# How to add one positional srgument in aiogram middleware?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

I have several files.
The task is to configure the middleware so that it adds the user to the local database after pressing the start button in telegram bot.
As a result I get an error.
Here it is:

> TypeError: on_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

File middleware.py:

```
from typing import Dict, Any, Callable, Awaitable

from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler


class SchedulerMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
def __init__(self, scheduler: AsyncIOScheduler):
self.scheduler = scheduler

async def __call__(self,
handler: Callable[[Message, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
event: Message,
data: Dict[str, Any],
) -> Any:
data['scheduler'] = self.scheduler
return await handler(event, data)
```

File db_middleware.py

```
from typing import Callable, Awaitable, Dict, Any

from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message


class DbSession(BaseMiddleware):
def __init__(self, connector):
self.connector = connector

async def __call__(self,
handler: Callable[[Message, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
event: Message,
data: Dict[str, Any],
) -> Any:
async with self.connector.connection() as connect:
data['request'] = Request(connect)
return await handler(event, data)`
```

File fsm.py:

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.filters import Command, Text
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import BotCommand, BotCommandScopeDefault
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

from LearnBot.middleware.middleware import SchedulerMiddleware
from LearnBot.others.db_connect import Request
from main import States

token = "5100032963:***"


class States(StatesGroup):
first_name = State()
last_name = State()
telephone = State()
complete = State()
cancel = State()


async def comm(bot: Bot):
command = [
BotCommand(
command='start',
description='Начало работы',
),
BotCommand(
command='help',
description='Помощь',
),
]

await bot.set_my_commands(command, BotCommandScopeDefault())


async def on_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, request: Request):
await message.reply("Введите необходимые даные\nВведите имя " + message.text)
await request.add_user(message)
await state.set_state(States.first_name)


def register_fsm(dp: Dispatcher):
dp.message.register(cancel, States.complete, Text(text='cancel', ignore_case=True))

dp.message.register(on_start, Command(commands='start'))


async def start():
try:
logging.basicConfig(
level=logging.INFO
)

bots = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher()

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')

# scheduler.add_job(run_interval_args, 'interval', seconds=10, args=(55,))
dp.update.middleware.register(SchedulerMiddleware(scheduler))
dp.message.register(on_start, Command(commands='start'))
scheduler.start()

await dp.start_polling(bots)
except Exception as ex:
print(ex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
asyncio.run(start())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to pass pull requests in file "db_middleware.py"

```
import asyncpg    
class DbSession(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, connector: asyncpg.pool.Pool):
        super().__init__()
        self.connector = connector
```